# Displaying features on JMapPane in GeoTools from postgresql database table geometry column?

Tags: shapefile, postgresql, java, geotools

I am making a GIS maven project in GeoTools.

How can we display data from the PostgreSQL database in GeoTools?

Presently I can display the shapefile from the file path, but I want to display this shapefile from the PostgreSQL database. So I could run spatial queries here in GeoTools. I gave all the dependency for connectivity of PostgreSQL database to GeoTools in pom.xml file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,
I have already applied this solution. But here filenotfound exception has occurred. I think here also i can't open the table (exported shape file from the QGIS) from the postgresql database.
In my project I have made a shape file in QGIS and import this shape file into the postgresql database. Now here this is in the form of table in which a column called geometry column. I want to display my shape file on JMapframe from this exported shape file (geometry column of the table in postgresql) of the postgresql. My code is.....
[![enter image description here](http://i.stack

Comment: take out the URL from the parameters - there is no need for any reference to the old shapefile

Answer (score 1):

The process for displaying a `Layer` in [GeoTools](http://geotools.org) is exactly the same regardless of where the data is stored so your question boils down to "how do I read in features from PostGIS?"

Currently your code must (should) construct a parameters map with the URL of the shapefile and passes that to `DataStoreFinder`:

```
String lines = "./linetest.shp";
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("url", DataUtilities.fileToURL(new File(lines)));
DataStore ds = DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
```

You then get a `FeatureSource` and combine it with a `Style` to make a `Layer`:

```
String type = ds.getTypeNames()[0];
FeatureLayer layer = new FeatureLayer(ds.getFeatureSource(type), style);
```

To do this with a PostGIS datastore is simply a case of creating the required parameters for the PostGIS connection and doing everything else the same. Helpfully the [PostGIS datastore page](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/jdbc/postgis.html) of the documentation provides example code:

```
Map<String,Object> params = new HashMap<String,Object>();
params.put( "dbtype", "postgis");
params.put( "host", "localhost");
params.put( "port", 5432);
params.put( "schema", "public");
params.put( "database", "database");
params.put( "user", "postgres");
params.put( "passwd", "postgres");

DataStore dataStore=DataStoreFinder.getDataStore(params);
```

The only other difference is that now instead of only one `typename` as with the shapefile now you have a choice of one for each *geographic* table in the database.